# Why won't "click" event fire on iPhone 6?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ajax

Ok, so my web app is working on MacOS 10.13 (Chrome), iPhone XR (Safari), iPhone SE (Gen 1, Safari).  When I try it on my iPhone 6 however, some of my buttons won't click...  As you can see in the code snippet, this works on almost everything (I am not trying to support IE or really old browsers), but it just doesn't do anything on iPhone 6 (safari)

```js
function checkID(a, b) {
  if (document.getElementById(a)) {
    if (document.querySelector('#' + a).contains(b.target)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (checkID('loginSubmit', e)) {
    document.getElementById("loginSubmit").innerHTML = "clicked!";
    var username = document.getElementById('loginUsername').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('loginPassword').value;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        //Do something
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "https://example.com/", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("password=" + password + "&username=" + username);
  }
});
```

```css
.login {
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.login p {
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.login-btn {
  width: 100%;
  background: #68AFD2;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 12px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 16pt;
}

.login-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.login-input {
  width: calc(100% - 14px);
  border: 1px solid rgb(240, 240, 240);
  padding-right: 6px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class='login'>
    <p>Login</p>
    <input class='login-input' id='loginUsername' type='text' name='username' placeholder='username...' required>
    <input style='margin-top:6px' class='login-input' id='loginPassword' type='password' name='password' placeholder='password...' required>
    <div id='loginSubmit' class='login-btn'>Login</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please stop using divs instead of buttons. `<div class="btn"` -> `<button class="btn"`

Comment: @evolutionxbox using buttons causes display problems on many browsers though...

Comment: Display problems? Not sure I agree there.

Comment: I used button, and it works (with display issues like borders and stuff), but some of my divs work just fine...

Comment: @evolutionxbox The divs that work use e.target && e.target.id == 'elementID'  whereas the broken ones use my checkID function...  querySelector doesn't work on iPhone 6?

Comment: Which version of iOS? --- Also please read https://benfrain.com/converting-divs-into-accessible-pseudo-buttons/

Comment: @evolutionxbox 12.5.0

Comment: Yes. iOS 12.5.0 supports querySelector https://caniuse.com/queryselector

Comment: @evolutionxbox What could be wrong with my function?  What is different?

Comment: Honestly I don't know. I don't have access to iOS 12.5.0 to find out. Do you get any errors in the console? (Remember to use Safari on mac to test)